# MySQL Select statement with where condition and inner join

Tags: mysql

I am using Geodesic Solutions. I need help with a query since I'm making an addon.
The tables in my database that I need to query are

```
geodesic_leveled_field_value_languages
 -id
 -language_id
 -name

geodesic_leveled_field_value
 -id
 -leveled_id
 -parent
 -leveled_field
 -enabled
 -display_order
```

My Sql Statement is

```php
$sqlSelect = "SELECT geodesic_leveled_field_value_languages.name AS \"FieldName\", geodesic_leveled_field_value.leveled_field AS \"FieldLevel\" FROM `geodesic_leveled_field_value` INNER JOIN `geodesic_leveled_field_value_languages` on geodesic_leveled_field_value.id = geodesic_leveled_field_value_languages.id";
```

I want it to return only the Names (from geodesic_leveled_field_value_languages table) for a specific leveled_value (in geodesic_leveled_field_value table)

I've also tried the following query but no luck

```php
 $sqlSelect = "SELECT geodesic_leveled_field_value_languages.name AS \"FieldName\", geodesic_leveled_field_value.leveled_field AS \"FieldLevel\" FROM `geodesic_leveled_field_value` where geodesic_leveled_field_value.leveled_field = 2 INNER JOIN `geodesic_leveled_field_value_languages` on geodesic_leveled_field_value.id = geodesic_leveled_field_value_languages.id";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with the following query,

```php
$sqlSelect = "SELECT geodesic_leveled_field_value_languages.name FROM `geodesic_leveled_field_value` INNER JOIN `geodesic_leveled_field_value_languages` on geodesic_leveled_field_value.id = geodesic_leveled_field_value_languages.id and geodesic_leveled_field_value.leveled_field = 2";
```

Basically I just added an `AND` statement after `ON` clause.
It selects the data from the two tables based on both the `ON` clauses.

Answer (score 1):

The sql will look something like this:

```
SELECT 
    gl.name
FROM
    geodesic_leveled_field_value_languages gl 
    INNER JOIN geodesic_leveled_field_value gv ON gv.id = gl.id
WHERE
    gv.level='required level value'
```

NOTE: This sql assumes that the level column is the column you want to filter data with and also assumes that both tables are connected with the id fileds.

You were missing the select clause where you specify each column from which table you want to return and you were missing the where condition that specifies what to return based in a filter criteria

You can learn more about sql.where clause in the following link
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Note that gl and gv are aliases.
You can find out more about aliases on the url

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with tying

You know your database and should know which fields build a relationship.

Further you can also use aliases for the tables, that will in future save you some time.

Also you can use between two double quotes a single quote or vice versa

the field leveled_field  in yr query is not in any of the two tables, so i am gusssing you meant the level

```
$sqlSelect = "SELECT gvl.name AS 'FieldName', gv.level AS 'FieldLevel' FROM `geodesic_leveled_field_value`  gv INNER JOIN `geodesic_leveled_field_value_languages` gvl on gv.id = gvl.id WHERE gv.level > 5;"
```

Comment: I didn't make the database, I'm fairly new to SQL, and the database was automatically created by Geocore. The connection between the tables is the Ids column in both tables

Comment: without data, everything is a guess i changed it to the id, as you menbtioned.